# Why am I suddenly getting an Unknown word error in Nuxt?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js

I have a Nuxt project that was working fine until today.

Within this project, I am using Vue Flickity, which includes a link to a Flickity CSS file in `node_modules`. This has been working fine until now and seems to be the root of the issue.

When I run `npm run dev` I get the following error:

> ERROR  in
>   ./node_modules/flickity/dist/flickity.css?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css&
>   friendly-errors 16:00:12
>
> Syntax Error: ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from
>   ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):      friendly-errors
>   16:00:12 SyntaxError
>
> (141:7) Unknown word
>
> 139 |   140 |     if(module.hot) {
>
> > 141 |       // 1548777611244
> >           |       ^   142 |       var cssReload = require("../../extract-css-chunks-webpack-plugin/dist/hotModuleReplacement.js")(module.id,
> >     {"fileMap":"{fileName}","reloadAll":true});   143 |
> >     module.hot.dispose(cssReload);                                                                              > friendly-errors 16:00:12  @
> >     ./node_modules/flickity/dist/flickity.css?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css&
> >     1:0-576 1:592-595 1:597-1170 1:597-1170  @
> >     ./node_modules/vue-flickity/src/flickity.vue  @
> >     ./plugins/vue-flickity.js  @ ./.nuxt/index.js  @ ./.nuxt/client.js  @
> >     multi eventsource-polyfill
> >     webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true&timeout=30000&ansiColors=&overlayStyles=&name=client&path=/__webpack_hmr/client
> >     ./.nuxt/client.js

Screenshot:

[image]

I used the cli to create the project and so haven't even touched any Webpack configuration.

Vue Flickity is called via a plugin (as is the recommended way within Nuxt) with SSR set to false. Again, however, it has always been this way and was working fine before.

I can't understand why this is happening. Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug in nuxt 2.4.0.
It was fixed in 2.4.2 that was released https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/releases/tag/v2.4.2

Answer (score 0):

I have often faced this issue in Nuxt3, and downgrading the node to `16.19.1` version works.

Answer (score -1):

You probably have the Nuxt version defined as `"nuxt": "^2.3.4"` in your `package.json` so it automatically updated to Nuxt 2.4.0. Change it to `"nuxt": "2.3.4"` and run npm install.